# why while calling camera in android all varibles in the activity are reinitilized?

Tags: android, android-camera, sharedpreferences

I am newbie to android, i faced a problem with camera in android.
In my class, i have some instance variables(holding some values) and a button and image view.
when i click that button the application opens camera and stores in sd card, after that i am doing some operations with instance variables.
 But the problem is the variables are reinitialized to default values.
i have used shared preference or storing(variables data) in another class as static variables  then it works fine.
My question is why all instance variables are reinitialized.
And how to overcome that problem ?

Is SharedPreference,storing(variables data) in another class as static variables s is only solution ?

camera code

```
 public void openCamera() {
    if (Helper.checkCameraHardware(this)) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String dateFileName = sdf.format(new Date()); // generating
                                                            // todays date
                                                            // for folder

            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            String curentDateandTime = sdf1.format(new Date()); // generating
                                                                // todays
                                                                // date with
                                                                // min,seconds
                                                                // for image

            // creating an folder in sd card : ed ==> sdCard path/IMG_Folder
            // in helper class / folder with todays date
            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/"
                    + Helper.IMG_FOLDER + "/" + dateFileName);
            if (!sdImageMainDirectory.exists()) { // if folder not exists it
                                                    // created
                sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
            }

            // setting image path to sd card/Img_folder in helper
            // class/todays date folder
            image_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getPath()
                    + "/"
                    + Helper.IMG_FOLDER
                    + "/"
                    + dateFileName + "/";
            // creating a new file(jpg) at above image path
            File file = new File(image_PATH, curentDateandTime + ".jpg");

            // re-initilization of image_PATH to new file(jpg)
            image_PATH = image_PATH + curentDateandTime + ".jpg";
            savePreferences();

            // creating an uri for file
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1234);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Helper.AlertBox(this,
                    "Error No: 001\nPlease Contact us.\n"
                            + e.toString());
        }
    } else {
        Helper.AlertBox(this, "Camera Not Found.!");
    }
}




public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // image_PATH = "";
    image_str = "";

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1234) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            restorePreferences();

            System.out.println("image_PATH :" + image_PATH);

            File file = new File(image_PATH);
            if (file.exists()) {

                Log.e("File exist :", "File exist at " + image_PATH);

                FileInputStream in;
                BufferedInputStream buf;
                try {
                     in = new FileInputStream(image_PATH);
                     buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                     bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);

                     iv_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     iv_image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                     ConstantClass.image_PATH = image_PATH;

                     if (in != null) {
                     in.close();
                     }
                     if (buf != null) {
                     buf.close();
                     }

                    intent = new Intent(TakePhoto.this, PhotoPreview.class);
                    intent.putExtra("index", Helper.index);
                    Helper.bitMap[Helper.index] = image_PATH;
                    Log.e("test", "1");

                    Helper.btn[Helper.index] = false;
                    Log.e("test", "2");

                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.e("test", "3");

                    // Helper.AlertBox(this, "Image Captured.");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Helper.AlertBox(this,
                            "Error No: 004\nPlease contact Bluefrog technical person.\n"
                                    + e.toString());
                    Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
                }

            } else {
                Helper.AlertBox(this,
                        "Error No: 005\nPlease contact Bluefrog technical person.");
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cam Not Supported",
                    5000).show();
        }
    }
}
```

here Helper.index(I have stored in some class as static varible)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are there an errors showing in the LogCat?

Comment: Sir, in my application Activity1--(calling)->Activity2[this has a button and an imageview], here i am passing some data through intent from Activity1 to Activity2, In Activity2 (in Activity2 i am getting data successfully before calling camera ) if am calling camera,the data which i got from intent are reinitialized to default values.To avoid this i have not passed the data from Activity1(i have stored in SharedPreference or in constant class as static variables it works fine).My question is are these only solutions?

Comment: So, I assume no errors are showing up in the LogCat?  (and you don't have to call me 'sir', Damien is fine :) )

Comment: @Damien,because i am using (SharedPreference or storing in constant class as static variables it works fine). but if i pass through intent(the data from Activity1 to  Activity2) and calling camera in Activity2 all the data which i got from Activity1 are reinitialized with default values.And in LogCat im getting error ArrayIndexOutOfBounds [because of data which i got from Activity1 are reinitialized, i have solved this problem bu using shared preference or storing in static varible].

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now and good on you for finding the solution that you have.  I'll have a think and search, as I can not immediately answer if these are the only solutions, but they may be the best ones.